# Obtaining stringArray from another Class

Tags: android, arrays

I'm assuming this is a really basic and a newb mistake but I am trying to get a StringArray for my ArrayAdapter from another class. I am even unsure if I have the correct idea, I am self taught beginner so any help is much appreciated.

My MainActivity.java snippet:

```
    Gold gold = new Gold();
    ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, gold.maxArray(highestLevel));
    ArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And my Gold.java snippet:

```
public class Gold extends MainActivity{

String[] maxUpgradeLevel;

public String[] maxArray (int maxLevel) {
    if (maxLevel == 1){
        return maxUpgradeLevel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.level1_entries_spinner);
    } else if (maxLevel == 2) {
        return maxUpgradeLevel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.level2_entries_spinner);
    } else if (maxLevel == 3) {
        return maxUpgradeLevel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.level3_entries_spinner);
    } else if (maxLevel == 4) {
        return maxUpgradeLevel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.level4_entries_spinner);
```

and so on....

My logcat tells me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So I've been here for a few hours trying to tweak the code, the code was working fine before when I was using `Integer[]` but when I started with `String[]` I apparently can no longer get the resource.

Should I just put the content of Gold.java straight into MainActivity.java or is there a way of doing this that I am not aware of?

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't use the `new` operator on classes that extends `Activity`. The `Activity` has to go through its lifecycle before you can use the Activity's context to  access the resources. If you need to access `maxArray` from different classes and you don't want to replicate the code, you can make the method static, and pass a Context object as parameter.

```
public class Gold {


   public static String[] maxArray (Context context, int maxLevel) {
      if (maxLevel == 1){
         return context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.level1_entries_spinner);
      }
      //
```

and you can reference it like `Gold.maxArray(this, maxLevel)` from `onCreate` of your `Activity`. It it is use just in one place, then you can move the code as `private` method of your Activity

Answer (score 1):

**Never create an instance for activity class.** Activity instances should be created only through intents.

Fundamentally `Gold gold = new Gold();` is wrong if Gold is extended class of `MainActivity` or any other activity.

Change your MainActivity call:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Gold.maxArray(getResources(),highestLevel));
```

and your Gold.java

```
    public class Gold {


        public static String[] maxArray (Resources res, int maxLevel) {
                if (maxLevel == 1){
                    return  res.getStringArray(R.array.level1_entries_spinner);
                } else if (maxLevel == 2) {
                    return  res.getStringArray(R.array.level2_entries_spinner);
                } else if (maxLevel == 3) {
                    return  res.getStringArray(R.array.level3_entries_spinner);
                } else if (maxLevel == 4) {
                    return  res.getStringArray(R.array.level4_entries_spinner);
                }
    //..
            }
        }
    }
```